# how to serialize JSONB field with marshall in flask restplus?

Tags: flask, marshalling, flask-restplus

having model sqlalchemy like this

```
class Action(base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parameters = Column(JSONB)
```

how can I define serialization of parameters using flask restplus api.Model marshall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by using `fields.Raw`

```
action_serializer = api.model('Action', {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'parameters': fields.Raw
})
```

moreover, you can even reach for nested attr like this:

`'name': fields.String(attribute='parameters.name')`